# eloquent get all row of a table and edit a field

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm a newbie on laravel and I'm trying to use Eloquent to edit a field for all rows of a MySQL table.

So I create that:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Mining;
use DB;

class FrontendController extends Controller{
    public function cronDiff(){
        $basic = GeneralSettings::first();
        $row = Mining::all()->whereStatus(1)->get();
        foreach ($row as $coins){
            $code = Mining::where('coin_code', $coins->coin_code)->get();
            $risultato = difficolta($code);
            DB::table['minings']->insert('coin_code' => $code); 
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a table `minings` like this:

```
id->int
name->varchar
coin_code->varchar
coin_diff->varchar
status->tinyint
```

But I can't update `coin_diff` using the value of `$risultato` (taken from other function)
Can you help to find out where I'm wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `->update('coin_code' => $code);` instead `->insert`

I think this solution would be better:

```
$minings = DB::table('minings')->get();

$minings->coin_code = $code;
$minings->update();
```

Comment: this inside for cycle?

Comment: try this instead of your DB::table['minings']->insert('coin_code' => $code);

Comment: nothing also with that lines it doesn't work. maybe the for cycle it's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It should work like that: `Mining::update(['coin_code' => $code])` if you have conditions you can chain them before update.

Also, you need to have the columns on models $fillable property. So, i don't know what error do you get but it might be from that.

Comment: Hi, thanks, it doesn't work also with update instead insert maybe the error is on `$row = Mining::all()->whereStatus(1)->get();` ?

Comment: Well you do have an error there, `Mining::all()`, means that you get all the rows from that table and after that apply another methods which won't work, you need to get rid of `all()->` and leave only Mining::whereStatus(1)->get();

Comment: You should post the error too, that way people will help you faster

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update then why are you using insert?!

If you want to update a single row then modify your code

`DB::table['minings']->insert('coin_code' => $code);`
 to 

`$coins->update(['coin_code' => $risultato]);`

**And make sure that `$risultato` have string value**

Comment: Ok, now i've that :
` public function cronDiff(){
        $basic = GeneralSettings::first();
        $row = Mining::all()->get();
        foreach ($row as $coins){
            $code = Mining::where('coin_code', $coins->coin_code)->get();
            $risultato = difficolta($code);
            $risultato2 = (string)$risultato;
            $coins->update(['coin_code' => $risultato]);
        }
    }
`

but it doesn't work again maybe i'm wrong on get row?
on that line :
`
$row = Mining::all()->get();`

?

Comment: try this `$row = Minig::where('status',1)->get()` instead of `$row = Mining::all()->whereStatus(1)->get();`